# sqlite3 boolean field storing text value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I dont know how the boolean data type column defined in sqlite3 is able to store a text type data.

I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sometable` (
    `name`  text,
    `bool_field` boolean
);
```

and ran the below insert query:

```
insert into `sometable` values ('name1','something');
```

and it  worked like a charm without throwing any error. I am surprised - guys any idea why ? I know about the association of boolean field in sqlite3 is with numeric 1 and 0. but how come text getting stored here ?

Version Info:

SQLite Version 3.9.2

Used a client called "DB Browser for SQLite" for Ubuntu Version 3.7.0 (built on Qt version 5.5.1)

Comment: Thanks GurV for the code edit :)

Comment: What happens if you insert other string values, and if you select from the table?

Comment: I tried with : 
select * from sometable; 
and it worked 
Even tried with :
"insert into `sometable` values ('name1','something really huge');" and it works all the same

Comment: And you get the same values back? Amazing.

Comment: Yup I get the same values :) Quite surprising